# Bukkit custom inventory Spawn Egg (#2)

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to add a creeper egg inside my custom GUI menu.
This is what I completed so far:

```
    ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(Material.MONSTER_EGG, 1, EntityType.CREEPER.getTypeId());

    ItemMeta meta = stack.getItemMeta();
    meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Creeper");
    stack.setItemMeta(meta);
    inv.setItem(1, stack);
    player.openInventory(inv);
    return true;
```

My question is: How do I add the creeper egg to my InventoryClick class?

```
    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();
    ItemStack item = event.getCurrentItem();
    if (item.getType() == Material.blah blah) {
        player.performCommand("blah blah");

        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean add? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I finished my first class, in which adds in the creeper egg. But I also need it for my InventoryClick, so it knows like when you click it, and it knows to perform a command once you click the egg. So I am confused, because I don't know what to do in the inventoryClick class if I am adding a creeper egg in the GUI :P

Comment: why do have separate *classes*?

Comment: To separate the InventoryClick and the actual main command to execute the GUI open.

Comment: But why? Can't you set up an event listener in the same class? If you absolutely need to, set up a getter for the item

Comment: It just seems easier for me for the packages. Anyway, do you got thoughts on the creeper egg for the second class? I have no clue, haha

Comment: Can you show more code? An idea is to set up a getter to get the item

Comment: Indeed. http://hastebin.com/yiyahezacu.swift | http://hastebin.com/urewemujen.swift

Comment: You can add metadata to your item, and then onClickEvent check if that's the metadata you need

Answer (score 0):

For retrieving a specific Item you created, check if the monster egg you're clicking is a creeper MONSTER_EGG.

**Checking if it's a creeper spawn egg:**

**IF VERSION IS BELOW 1.9:**

```
ItemStack item;
boolean isSpawnEgg = item.getType() == Material.MONSTER_EGG;
    if (isSpawnEgg) {
        SpawnEgg egg = (SpawnEgg) item.getData();
        EntityType type = egg.getSpawnedType();
        if (type.equals(EntityType.CREEPER) ){
        //IsACreeper
        }
    }
```

**IF VERSION IS 1.9 OR ABOVE:**

Currently not supported in Bukkit/Spigot API without using NBT. If you want to use NBT, [THIS CLASS](https://gist.github.com/tastybento/6053eeb68c1c19d33540) might be of help.

Comment: Why does 1.9 need an other method to get the creeper egg?

Comment: @Ferrybig As of SPIGOT-1592, the spawnedtype won't work anymore, as the type is now stored inside metadata, so that method for SpawnEggs won't work.